# Jquery UI autocomplete select by category as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Using the resources available on the jQuery UI website

[jQuery UI Autocomplete with categories](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)

I have been able to modify my select box to become a jQuery UI autocomplete. The selectbox in question has optgroups which act as the categories.

```
var dataSource = [];
$("#selectauser").find("option").each(function () {
    var $me = $(this);
    dataSource.push({
        "label": $me.text(),
        "id": $me.attr("value"),
        "category": $me.parent().attr("label")
    });
});
```

If a user begins to type a category name is there a way to show all the children under that category.

For example... given the following menu.

> - Animals
>
>   - Dog
>   - Cat
>   - Fish
> - Films
>
>   - Lord of the Rings
>   - Harry Potter
>   - Another film name

If I typed "an" it would return

> - Animals
>
>   - Dog
>   - Cat
>   - Fish
> - Films
>
>   - Another film name

As the animals header contains "an" it would return all the animals, and as the films has an option called "Another film name" it would also return this.

I found that commenting out the line here would allow the visual effect of picking the header, but filtering on it still does not appear to work.

```
this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
```

and that logging the items parameter from the

```
_renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
```

line only returns the values that are being shown in the list, so I believe something needs to be done before this.

Any help/pointers in the right direction would be helpful.